# Quill.js and zombie.js

Tags: node.js, contenteditable, jsdom, zombie.js, quill

Trying to test quill.js editor (contenteditable div) in the zombie.js headless browser.

1. Complaining about document.getSelection missing
2. Complaining about document.createTreeWalker missing
3. Doesn't seem to respond if I manually dispatch a change event using the DOM node of the editor.

Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's what I've found:

1. document.getSelection isn't supported by the current (old) version of jsdom which zombie.js uses. I've had to monkey-patch it for now. There is a pending PR for zombie.js that should update jsdom to a later version where these are available: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/939
2. document.createTreeWalker - same
3. turns out that quill.js is listening for "keyup" or "keydown" rather than "change", so need to dispatch those instead.

Below are some terrible  monkey-patches of the missing DOM methods which turn out to be adequate for testing the bare minimum of quill.js:

```
var zombie = require( "zombie" );
zombie.Pipeline.addHandler(function(browser, request, response) {

    browser.document.getSelection = browser.window.getSelection = function() {

        console.warn( "getSelection called - monkey-patched, incorrect implementation" );
        return null;

    };
    browser.document.createTreeWalker = function( x ) {

        console.warn( "createTreeWalker called - monkey-patched, incorrect implementation" );
        return {

            currentNode: x,
            nextNode: function() {

                if( this.currentNode.childNodes && this.currentNode.childNodes.length ) {

                    this.currentNode = this.currentNode.childNodes[ 0 ];

                } else if( this.currentNode.nextSibling ) {

                    this.currentNode = this.currentNode.nextSibling;

                } else if( this.currentNode.parentNode ) {

                    this.currentNode = this.currentNode.parentNode.nextSibling;

                }
                return this.currentNode || null;

            }

        };

    };
    return response;

} );
```